# SegFault when switching from small test file to 31 mb file

Tags: c, multithreading

Below is my (incomplete) code for a merge sort project. This worked fine for the parts I have implemented until I switched from the 128 line test file to the 31 mb file that is supposed to be sorted. Now getting a segfault and I'm not sure what to do in order to solve this.

Removed some lines I believe are inconsequential because "mostly code".

```
struct Record {
    char key[KEYSIZE+1];
    char data[DATASIZE+1];
};
int threadCount;
int tiers;
static struct ThdArg {
        int thdNum; // Thread number 0,1,2,3
        struct Record * lowRec; // First record of group or first index of record
        struct Record * hiRec;  // Last record of group or last index of record   
};


int lines;
int tiers;
void *threadFunc(void *var)
{
    struct ThdArg temp2 = *((struct ThdArg*)var);
    qsort((temp2.lowRec), lines/threadCount, sizeof(struct Record), comparator);
    for(int k=0;k<tiers;k++)
        if(temp2.thdNum%(int)(pow(2,k+1))==0)
        {
            qsort((temp2.lowRec), lines/(threadCount/(int)pow(2,k+1)), sizeof(struct Record),comparator);   

        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Please enter a file name");
        return 0;
    }
    threadCount =8;

    tiers =(int)log2((double)threadCount);
    pthread_t threads[threadCount];
    FILE *recordFile=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char ch;
    fseek(recordFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lines = ftell(recordFile);
    fseek(recordFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lines=lines/64;

    struct Record recArr[lines]; 

    char  buffer[9];
    char buffer2[57];
    for(int j=0;j<lines;j++)
    {
        fgets(buffer, 9, recordFile);
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            recArr[j].key[i]=buffer[i];
        }
        recArr[j].key[8]='\0';
        fgets(buffer2, 57, recordFile);
        for(int i=0;i<56;i++)
        {
            recArr[j].data[i]=buffer2[i];
        }
        recArr[j].data[57]='\0';
    }
    struct ThdArg temp[threadCount];
    for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++)
    {
        temp[i].thdNum = i;
        temp[i].lowRec=&recArr[(lines/threadCount)*i];
        temp[i].hiRec=&recArr[(lines/threadCount)*(i+1)-1];
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL, threadFunc, (void *)&temp[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    } 

}
```

Comment: `qsort()` in a merge sort implementation?

Comment: qsort() was included in the project's specifications so yes

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks, I gave a specific error and a specific circumstance in which it happens but this will surely help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line:

```
struct Record recArr[lines];
```

allocates memory on the stack. Its size is restricted.
If you read a file which can be be very big use malloc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  {
    char key[KEYSIZE +1];
    char data[DATASIZE +1];
}Record;

...

recArr = malloc(sizeof(Record) * lines);
...
free(recArr);
```

You can use the pointer like an array. (In fact, they are the same)

Comment: `You can use the pointer like an array. (In fact, they are the same)`... Well... No. They are NOT the same. arrays can decay to pointers, but are not pointers. One of the difference i can think of is when you apply the sizeof operator on arrays / pointers.

Comment: Thanks, how exactly do I declare recArr when using it like this though?